# Prove $\displaystyle\sup_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{A_n\}$ be two sequences of non-negative numbers. Then:

$$\displaystyle\sup_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n}.$$

Is this right or wrong? Can you explain for me? Thanks.

Comment: Let add a couple of words. Let $ B_n = \sum_1^n a_j $. $\{B_n\}$ is an increasing sequence, and no restriction is imposed on it. So take any increasing $\{B_n\}$, divergent, and take $A_n = B_n^2$, then the supremum on the right side is $\frac{1}{B_1}$, and the limit on the left is 0.

Answer (score 5):

Take $a_1 = 1, a_k = 0$ for $k \neq 1$. Take $A_n = n$.

Then 
$\displaystyle\sup_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n} = 1$,
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k}{A_n} = 0$.